# How to define a function to sum up the max and min from a list

Tags: python

```
def sum_num()
numbers=input("Please enter a sequence of comma-separated numbers:\n")
mynumbers=numbers.split(",")
print(mynumbers)
mylist=[]
maxnum= max(mynumbers)
minnum = min(mynumbers)
print(int(maxnum)+int(minnum))

return sum_num()
```

Why the define function does not work?
Really confused!

Now as you mentioned, I changed my codes to as below:

```
def sum_num():  
    numbers=input("Please enter a sequence of comma-separated numbers:\n")
    mynumbers=numbers.split(",")
    print(mynumbers)
    mylist=[]
    maxnum= max(mynumbers)
    minnum = min(mynumbers)
    print(int(maxnum)+int(minnum))

sum_num()
```

Still feel confused about it. Can anyone tell me how to call the function to test?

Comment: well is your indentation correct?

Comment: Please indent your code. At first glance, the problem is that you need to convert `mynumbers` to `int` before applying max and min.

Comment: Also, missing colon: `def sum_num()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def sum_num():
  numbers = input("Please enter a sequence of comma-separated numbers:\n")
  mynumbers = [int(x) for x in numbers.split(",") if x] # handling empty strings
  min_num, max_num = min(mynumbers), max(mynumbers)
  return min_num + max_num

print(sum_num())
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to find `min` and `max` on list of integers. So map your list of strings to list of integers.

I would also reorder the code like below, just because, now `sum_num` can be called on any list:

```
def sum_num(lst):
    return max(lst) + min(lst)

numbers = input("Please enter a sequence of comma-separated numbers:\n")
mynumbers = numbers.split(",")

print(sum_num(list(map(int, mynumbers))))
```

Comment: Nice code, concise and straightforward. Thousands of thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def sum_num():
    numbers=input("Please enter a sequence of comma-separated numbers:\n")
    print(numbers)
    maxnum= max(numbers)
    minnum = min(numbers)
    print(int(maxnum) + int(minnum))

sum_num()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should edit

```
return sum_num()
```

to

```
return int(maxnum)+int(minnum)
```

get sum of these values.

and

```
print(sum_num())
```

you can use this codes to print that values.

```
def sum_num():

    numbers=input("Please enter a sequence of comma-separated numbers:\n")
    mynumbers=numbers.split(",")
    print(mynumbers)
    mylist=[]
    maxnum= max(mynumbers)
    minnum = min(mynumbers)
    print(int(maxnum)+int(minnum))

    return int(maxnum)+int(minnum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using built in `sum`, `min` and `max` you can also `sort` the list and return sum of element at `0` and `-1`

```
def sum_num():
  numbers = map(int,input("Please enter a sequence of comma-separated numbers:\n").split(',')
  numbers.sort()
  return numbers[0]+numbers[-1]

print(sum_num())
```